Add Unsubscribe headers with aws ses
I'm using aws Javascript SDK to send bulk emails.
However, I need to add unsubscribe headers, which I'm unsure how to
Here is my code:

import { SendBulkTemplatedEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import { SESClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";


const createBulkReminderEmailCommand = (users, templateName) => {
  return new SendBulkTemplatedEmailCommand({
    Destinations: users.map((user) => {
        // do something
      return {
        Destination: { ToAddresses: [user] },
        ReplacementTemplateData: JSON.stringify({ hashedUser }),
        // adding this does not work
      //   Headers: [ 
      //     { 
      //        Name: "List-Unsubscribe",
             
      //        Value: `<https://domain.tld/unsubscribe?id=${hashedUser}>, <mailto:unsub@mail.domain.tld?subject=TopicUnsubscribe>`
      //     },
      //     {
      //       Name: "List-Unsubscribe-Post",
      //       Value: "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click"            
      //     }
      //  ]
      };
    }),
    
    DefaultTemplateData: JSON.stringify({}),
    Source: VERIFIED_EMAIL,
    Template: templateName,
    ConfigurationSetName: "grow",
    
  });
};




    const sendBulkTemplateEmailCommand = createBulkReminderEmailCommand(
      emails,
      TEMPLATE_NAME
    );
      const res = await sesClient.send(sendBulkTemplateEmailCommand);


I've also checked this documentation, however, it is giving solution for python, and not javascript.
If you need further info, please let me know in the comments!

The doc you reference uses send_email, not templated emails like you try to use. I Have been looking for a solution my self but have not find anyone

Umm ok, let me know if you find any

It is possible with @aws-sdk/client-sesv2
See docs for sesv2 client, specifically the SendEmailCommand
